# implementing x(n+1) in digital circuit

Tags: digital-logic, fpga

Implementing a delay is easy but I wonder is it possible to advance a signal? if so then is the circuit more complex than delay? I was just doing a DSP problem of plotting signal x(-n+k) and there are two ways we can do so by folding and delaying or by advancing and folding. I thought may be delay is better way cause it probably would be easier when it goes in terms of implement circuit. I have no idea if that logic makes sense or not?

Comment: What? You should start from the beginning not from the middle. Show some examples to clarify.

Comment: Real-world circuits are causal. A causal circuit at time 'n' doesn't know what x(n+1) is going to be, so can't use it.

Comment: If you can build an x(n+1) circuit, I'll give you a million dollars, and then use it to predict the future

Comment: Build me a time machine please.

Comment: why does this concept exist then, if not practical at all?

Comment: Because `n` is not necessarily meaning the (real) time. Also there are algorithms/circuits for *predicting* (in the meaning of *estimating*) the value (who said Kalman filter?). And the term *future* exists, despite it is "not practical".

Comment: totally forgot about Kalman and other estimation algorithms. thanks @EugeneSh.

Answer (score 1):

As the comments suggest, if you want \$x(n+1)\$, you need to wait for it to arrive.  Of course, \$n\$ is arbitrary.  If you define time \$n\$ as ten samples ago, then you have available \$\{x(n+1), \ldots, x(n+9)\}\$.

If you want to predict (estimate) future values, you're asking a DSP question.  [Linear prediction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_prediction) is a common approach for predicting future samples and is used in applications such as the [audio coding (compression)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_predictive_coding) used in the GSM cell phone standard.